# Convert (CSV) File to JSONObject Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am doing an Web Application, and I would like to store a file to MongoDB

In JSP I have this:

```
<input type="file" name="thefile" id="thefile" value=""/>
```

In ActionForm I have this:

```
private FormFile thefile;
    public FormFile getThefile() {
        return thefile;
    }

    public void setThefile(FormFile thefile) {
        this.thefile = thefile;
    }
```

And in Action I have this:

```
FormFile file = theform.getThefile();
```

Until here works properly. But now I would like to convert this file to a JSONObject. (The file will be always CSV file)

Can anyone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

When the CSV file to be parsed is simple(there are no quoted fields or commas embedded in fields), you can use a simple pattern matcher to split the CSV fields.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",");
```

**Step 2:**

Create a Model Class. Let the model class named as `Model`. Create a constructor with all the fields of the class.

**Step 3:**

Reading the CSV data.

```
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));) {
    List<Player> players = in .lines() .skip(1) .map(line -> { 

    String[] x = pattern.split(line); 

    return new Player(Integer.parseInt(x[0]), x[1], x[2], x[3], Integer.parseInt(x[4])); }) .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Step 4:**

Serialize to JSON

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT); 
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(players);
```

So, the whole program will be:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",");

try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));) {
    List<Player>players = in .lines().skip(1).map(line - > {
        String[] x = pattern.split(line);
        return new Player(Integer.parseInt(x[0]), x[1], x[2], x[3], Integer.parseInt(x[4]));
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(players);    
}
```